# Getting process identifier always returns 0

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

So this code here is always returning 0 for my process identifier.

```
::std::uint32_t GetPID(const char* windowName)
{
    ::std::uint32_t pID; // when this is initialized to 0, my function returns 0 otherwise it returns rand

    HWND hWindow = FindWindow(NULL, (LPCWSTR)windowName);

    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWindow, &pID);

    return pID;
}
```

I have tried using my other function which gets the process identifier as well, which worked flawlessly before for me but it also returned 0. I've tried with other process names as well, but nothing worked.

I tried debugging it and I saw that when I initialize `pID` to 0, the function returns 0. I think this is because `FindWindow()`'s HWND is somehow invalid and therefore `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` doesn't set my `pID` variable to the process id so it remains as 0. Also, when I just define `pID`, my function returns random numbers that aren't pid's (garbage memory because it's not initialized, as if the handle from `FindWindow()` was invalid and therefore no Process identifier was assigned to my variable `pID` at `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`).

I think it is something with the `FindWindow()` function, but I've tried putting other process names in and there was no change. I could use `PROCESSENTRY32` but I want to know what's wrong with this.

I feel like the answer is right in front of me and I can't figure it out for some reason.

Comment: Do not use C style casts as in `(LPCWSTR)windowName`, instead use `reinterpret_cast` and only use that at all if you are absolutely sure you know what it does. Here your cast is not doing what you intend it to do.

Comment: I'd say the answer is your window's not found because the name is wrong. Do some error checking.

Comment: `(LPCWSTR)windowName` What do you think this does?

Comment: I thought that (LPCWSTR) casted my const char* to LPCWSTR

Comment: @hobbes1235 It does, but that makes no sense, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older windows API functions that take string arguments come in three variants, one taking narrow strings (`char`), one taking wide strings (`wchar_t`) and one taking either narrow or wide depending on the `UNICODE` macro setting (`tchar_t`).

The functions always taking narrow strings can be identified by an `A` at the end of the function name, the ones always taking a wide string by a `W`.

More recent API functions may not provide the narrow (ANSI) version at all, in which case the above does not apply. `FindWindow` is however not one of those cases.

You are using the variant with variable type and apparently the `UNICODE` setting changed for you, since you say that the code worked previously. However I am sure that you added the `(LPCWSTR)` cast later, because that cast is simply wrong in either case.

`(LPCWSTR)windowName` casts the `const char*` pointer to a `const wchar_t*` pointer (`LPCWSTR` is `const wchar_t*`), but it does not actually convert the narrow characters that the pointers point to into wide ones. For example on Windows wide characters are two bytes wide and therefore each two bytes of the array that `windowName` points to will be interpreted as one character when the function dereferences the pointer. But that obviously makes no sense. In particular the null-terminator is only one byte in `char`, but would need to be two bytes in `wchar_t`. It is therefore extremely unlikely that the `char` array that `windowName` points to will contain a properly aligned null-terminator for `wchar_t*`, leading to undefined behavior when the function is iterating the `wchar_t*` out-of-bounds.

Therefore you are in the best case scenario handing `FindWindow` gibberish as window name, but most likely you will have undefined behavior.

If you are passing a narrow string, use the appropriate function:

```
HWND hWindow = FindWindowA(NULL, windowName);
```

In general, never use C-style casts because they can do many unintended things. Instead use `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` or whatever other cast is appropriate. Single `static_cast`s are usually unproblematic, but as soon as you need to use `reinterpret_cast` you should be very cautious of what it is actually doing. C-style casts can do any of these casts and therefore hide this requirement for extra caution.

---

You also should always check the result of API calls for errors and handle them properly. That would have most likely showed you that something is wrong with the `FindWindow` call (even though there is undefined behavior already in the call). This is also necessary because you may not be able to guarantee that a window can actually be found in all calls to `GetPID` and then the `HWND` returned wouldn't be a valid window handle:

```
HWND hWindow = FindWindowA(NULL, windowName);

if(!hWindow) {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. I knew the differences between the functions but I thought that just casting strings when needed would be easier. I understand why that's a very bad idea now. Thanks :)

Comment: @hobbes1235 Since you might not be aware of it: You can *accept an answer* if you considered it most helpful in solving your problem, see [explanation here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). You are not required to do that, though.

Comment: @ErykSun In that case OP should probably change the function parameter from `const char* windowName` to `const wchar_t* windowName` or `LPCWSTR windowName` and adjust the caller side to use only wide strings.

Comment: @ErykSun Ah ok, thanks. I have added a paragraph to the question, but I don't actually have much experience working on Windows, so if something is wrong, imprecise or misunderstandable, then feel free to edit my answer, or let me know.

Comment: To my mind the biggest issue here is the lack of error checking. If you pass the output of one api call to another, without checking for errors, how can you tell which call failed?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have added a paragraph on that.